# Incrementing current date by 5 minutes in bash

Tags: bash, date

In my script I'm storing the current in date in a variable, however I would like the variable to store the date 5 minutes ahead.

```
29/10/2014-10:47:06 to 29/10/2014-10:52:06
```

Is there a quick and easy way to do this in Bash? Looking for a solution that would also work correctly if the time was 10:59:00 for example (recognising to enter the next hour).

I've found some Perl solutions but nothing for Bash.

Comment: This might work for you: `date -d '2014/10/29 10:47:06 + 5 minutes'`. Or if it's from the current date, `date -d '5 minutes'`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `-d` option:

```
$ date
mercredi 29 octobre 2014, 11:45:45 (UTC+0100)
$ date -d '5 mins'
mercredi 29 octobre 2014, 11:50:55 (UTC+0100)
```

And if you want to use a variable:

```
$ curr=$(date +%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S)
$ echo $curr
29/10/2014-11:59:50
$ date -d "($cur) +5mins" +%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S
29/10/2014-12:04:54
```

Comment: It seems the second example works only if you remove parentheses around $cur.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use -d option, with any user defined date:

```
 date -d '2014/10/29 10:58:06  5 minutes'
 Wed Oct 29 11:03:06 IST 2014
```

for current date

```
date -d '5 minutes'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the above options do not work for you, you may try the following:

According to the manual for "date" (man date), you may adjust the value of the current date with the "-v" option followed by `+/-{value}{y/m/w/d/H/M}`.

For example, the following commands will output the current date and the current date + 5 minutes:

```
username@pc-name ~ % date
Sun Oct 23 13:03:06 EEST 2022

username@pc-name ~ % date -v +5M
Sun Oct 23 13:08:15 EEST 2022
```

You may also apply formatting to the edited date:

```
username@pc-name ~ % date -v +5M +%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ
2022-10-23T13:08Z
```

Here is the documentation for this:

> When setting values (rather than adjusting them),
> seconds are in the range 0-59, minutes are in the
> range 0-59, hours are in the range 0-23, month days
> are in the range 1-31, week days are in the range
> 0-6 (Sun-Sat), months are in the range 1-12 (Jan-
> Dec) and years are in the range 80-38 or 1980-2038.

> If val is numeric, one of either y, m, w, d, H, M or
> S must be used to specify which part of the date is
> to be adjusted.

> The week day or month may be specified using a name
> rather than a number.  If a name is used with the
> plus (or minus) sign, the date will be put forwards
> (or backwards) to the next (previous) date that
> matches the given week day or month.  This will not
> adjust the date, if the given week day or month is
> the same as the current one.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `date`:
`date +%s` gives you the seconds since 1.1.1970, add 5*60 and convert it back using
`date --date='@<newTime>'`.

See `man date` in bash.

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, the following options are supported for `date` command:

```
 -a [-]sss.fff   Slowly adjust the time  by  sss.fff  seconds
                 (fff represents fractions of a second). This
                 adjustment can be positive or negative.  The
                 system's  clock  is  sped  up or slowed down
                 until  it  has  drifted  by  the  number  of
                 seconds  specified.  Only the super-user may
                 adjust the time.
```

So, use the following to add 5 mins (=300 seconds):

```
date -a 300
```

Comment: The `-a` option is not available on Red Hat 4.8.3-9.