# How to add time to the current timestamp in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I am attempting to automate a few tasks in Ansible and while I've gotten everything else to work, I need to have a start_time and end_time variable that adds time to the current timestamp as the ServiceNow system does not accept a current timestamp when creating a change request.

For example, I have a variable start_time as `"{{ lookup('pipe', date +\"%Y-%m-%d %r\"') }}"` but I would need that to be the current time +5 minutes for example.  Likewise on the end_date, but something like +15 minutes.

Comment: in fact your problem is to add some amount of time to a start_time?

Comment: That is correct, both start_time and end_time (I typo'd above and listed end_date).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to use [`lookup`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html)_plugins and [`pipe`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup.html#plugin-list), you may just add 5 mins by using `date +"%Y-%m-%d %r" -d "5 mins"`.

**Thanks to**

- [Incrementing current date by 5 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26628392/)

Nevertheless it is recommend to use Ansible variables like `ansible_date_time` from facts.

```yaml
date_time:
  date: '2021-11-23'
  day: '23'
  epoch: '1637678908'
  hour: '15'
  iso8601: '2021-11-23T14:48:28Z'
  iso8601_basic: 20211123T154828773386
  iso8601_basic_short: 20211123T154828
  iso8601_micro: '2021-11-23T14:48:28.773386Z'
  minute: '48'
  month: '11'
  second: '28'
  time: '15:48:28'
  tz: CET
  tz_offset: '+0100'
  weekday: Tuesday
  weekday_number: '2'
  weeknumber: '47'
  year: '2021'
```

Form there you could use `epoch`, `minute` or what would fit to your use case.

Comment: I was successful in getting time added using `date +"%Y-%m-%d %r" -d "+5 minutes"` however I would like to achieve this using a variable file instead of having to execute that command in each playbook and storing the variable.

Comment: Turns out you can have it stored as a variable like `"{{ lookup('pipe', 'date -d \"+5 minutes\" +\"%Y%m%d %r\"') }}"`

Answer (score 5):

Something like?

```
{{ ansible_date_time.date }}
{{ ansible_date_time.hour|int +1|int }}
{{ ansible_date_time.minute|int +15|int }}
```

Comment: This is also very good, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `strftime` filter to format times, Ansible's built-in fact gathering to get the current time, and a little bit of arithmetic to add an offset.

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ '%Y-%m-%d %r' | strftime(ansible_facts.date_time.epoch | int + 300 ) }}"
          - "{{ '%Y-%m-%d %r' | strftime(ansible_facts.date_time.epoch | int + 900 ) }}"
```

```
TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "2021-11-23 01:10:45 PM",
        "2021-11-23 01:20:45 PM"
    ]
}
```

Comment: This is very good, thank you!